# Startx Segmentation fault error after installing VirtualGuest Additions for Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, backtrack, x-server, segmentation-fault, startx

I have been using my backtrack version 5 on the Virtualbox for some time now but I had a resolution problem and after searching found out I better install VirtualGuest additions. However after installing it `startx` does not work anymore and gives me segmentation fault. as follows:

```
Segmentation fault at address 0x7f7b26129800
caught signal 11(segmentation fault). Server aborting
Please consult the http://wiki.x.org foundation support
Please check the log file at "var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
ddxSigGiveUp: closing log giving up. xinit: no such file or directory (errno 2). unable to connect to x server. xinit: no such process (errno 3). Server error.
```

Answer (score 0):

Сегодня столкнулась с такой же проблемой.
Segmentation fault at address *address
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Cannot assign requested address.
Дистрибутив Devuan ceres OpenRC, драйвер nouveau.
Произошла ошибка, как это обычно и бывает, после обновления ядра до 6.0.0.5.
Сам segmentation fault обозначает, что произошла критическая ошибка при исполнении кода драйвера.
В моем случае - это, вероятно, очередная оплошность разработчиков Devuan. У них часто бывает такое, что ядро обновляется, а драйвера - нет. В прошлый раз, например, у меня не работал тачпад из-за слишком новой версии Intel-media-va.
Поэтому, я просто буду ждать обновления ядра или nouveau.
Тебе же дать какой-то конкретный совет не могу, так, как недостаточно тут деталей и у меня не хватает опыта в решении подобных проблем.
Хочу лишь сказать, что надо копать в сторону драйвера видеокарты.

Comment: It is not in English